# Excel datetime changed to date but Excel still thinks its datetime

Tags: excel-2010

I have an excel spreadsheet. I copy in data from another source and 2 fields are datetime format, these 2 fields are headed OPEN and CLOSED. I need to order these 2 fields by OPEN then CLOSED so that I can see all calls opened on a date and the calls closed on the same date, then the day after, then the day after that etc. I highlight OPEN and CLOSED and choose REPLACE. I select "space & asterix" in Find What field and leave Replace With field blank. This removes the time from the fields. When I check using VBA the TEXT of the field is only date. However when I sort the 2 columns it still thinks that there is a time element included. So instead of showing all OPEN on 01/10/16 it orders by 01/10/16 09:15:33 which messes up the CLOSED order column.
I hope this makes sense.
If anyone can help with this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't read this. It was human error. I made a mistake. Excel is working fine.